# windows mailslot max size on local computer

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc

After researching windows mailsots for IPC within a local computer I'm a bit confused on what the max size the datagram can be. MSDN says

["A mailslot is a pseudofile that resides in memory, and you use standard file functions to access it. The data in a mailslot message can be in any form, but cannot be larger than 424 bytes when sent between computers. Unlike disk files, mailslots are temporary. When all handles to a mailslot are closed, the mailslot and all the data it contains are deleted."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365130(VS.85).aspx)

the "when sent between computers" is what's confusing me. Is there a max size if the data is only being sent from one local process to another on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Yes it can receive more then 400 bytes if the process's are on the same local computer. It can recieve up to the amount that the mailslot buffer is sent to